# PHP for loop just displays 1 element

Tags: php, xml, for-loop

I try to use `PHP for` and I'm pretty new to it. I have an `xml` file stored in a variable called `$xmlroot`. Here you can see my code:

```
<?php
    $xmlroot = $_POST['xmldata'];
    //echo "Your data is: " . $xmlroot;

    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadXML($xmlroot);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($xmlroot); $i++){
        echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('postalcode')->item($i)->nodeValue;
    }
?>
```

But it just displays me the first `XML tag`. It should display all tags called "postalcode". My `XML` file looks like this:

```
<root>
    <code>
        <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
        <name>Test1</name>
    </code>
    <code>
        <postalcode>67890</postalcode>
        <name>Test2</name>
    </code>
    <code>
        <postalcode>13579</postalcode>
        <name>Test3</name>
    </code>
    <code>
        <postalcode>02468</postalcode>
        <name>Test1</name>
    </code>
</root>
```

It should display 4 elements but it displays just 1. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `count($xmlroot)` is equal to `1`. If you're going to use a `for` loop, you need to use the `length` property to retrieve the number of elements.

It's easier with a `foreach` loop, though:

```
$xmlroot = file_get_contents('file.html');

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xmlroot);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('postalcode') as $postalcode) {
    echo $postalcode->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/81079)

Comment: Nice! You did it. Thank you very much! First I tried with `length` property, which doesn't work but then I noticed your edit. Foreach works perfect :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php) class in php:

e.g.

**php**

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_string("<root>
    <code>
        <postalcode>12345</postalcode>
        <name>Test1</name>
    </code>
    <code>
        <postalcode>67890</postalcode>
        <name>Test2</name>
    </code>
    <code>
        <postalcode>13579</postalcode>
        <name>Test3</name>
    </code>
    <code>
        <postalcode>02468</postalcode>
        <name>Test1</name>
    </code>
</root>");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Outputs:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [code] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [postalcode] => 12345
                    [name] => Test1
                )
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [postalcode] => 67890
                    [name] => Test2
                )
            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [postalcode] => 13579
                    [name] => Test3
                )
            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [postalcode] => 02468
                    [name] => Test1
                )
        )
)
```

so, to iterate, what you will do is:

```
foreach ($xml->code as $node)
{
    // Do something with $node - e.g.
    $postalcode = $node->postalcode;

    var_dump($postalcode);
}
```